# Cloud SQL instances stuck on `updating`

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We have an automated process which clones our production Cloud SQL instance,  so we can have an instance with data to test against.

Unfortunately we now have two instances which are stuck on `restarting`, with no way to kill them. We've tried via the UI and CLI with no luck. It's been like this for days. Any solutions?

It seems like other solutions have been to wait for Google support to manually kill them on their side.

Comment: Can you please provide some code of your tries or an error log?

Comment: I suggest that you have to contact Google Cloud Platform Support and open a support ticket so that the issue could be properly investigated.

Comment: @PhilippSh unfortunately while we pay for Cloud SQL we don't pay for the upgraded support, so it points us here to the forums.

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys this is part of our CI/CD pipeline. Probably 95% of the time it works, but every so often it doesn't. When it doesn't, most of the time we get that red ! and we can delete it and just retry. We've now however seen two cases where it just spins on "updating" for days and we cannot interact with it.  

We clone the production Cloud SQL instance with: gcloud sql instances clone --async --project "$GCP_PROJECT" "$GCP_PRODUCTION_INSTANCE_NAME" "$JOB_GCP_INSTANCE_NAME"